# WSO2 Oauth implementation

Tags: oauth, wso2

I'm new to wso2. I have wso2 identity server installed. I want to protect my WSO2 APIs with OAuth, Can you please guide me or refer me to a page that have simple steps?
Thanks in Advance
Kasi

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 API Manager for this.

https://wso2.com/api-management/

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Quick+Start+Guide